# An argument regarding showing two closed subspaces are equal in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and suppose $V$ and $W$ are two subspaces of $X$ such that $V\subset W$. Also, both $V$ and $W$ are closed subspaces of $X$.<sup>[Edited according to @G.Sassatelli's answer]</sup> To prove $V=W$, *it suffices to show* that any continuous linear functional on $W$ which vanishes on $V$ is identically equal to $0$.

---

This is an argument made in a proof in Temam's Navier Stokes Equations(page 13). Would anybody explain the "it suffices to show" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is not closed, it's not true: namely, pick $W=\overline V$.

If $V$ is closed and $x\in W\setminus V$, Hahn-Banach guarantees the existence of a continuous functional $\phi\in W'$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ such that $\phi(x)>\alpha$ and $\phi(y)<\alpha$ for all $y\in V$. Now, let's prove that, actually, $V\subseteq \ker \phi$. Suppose $\phi(y)\ne0$ for some $y\in V$, then $$\phi\left(\frac{\lvert \alpha\rvert+1}{\phi(y)}y\right)=\lvert \alpha\rvert+1>\alpha\\ \frac{\lvert \alpha\rvert+1}{\phi(y)}y\in V$$
Which contradicts the constructive hypothesis of $\phi$. So, $\phi$ is a continuous functional on $W$ which is $0$ on $V$ but not on the whole $W$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying that one should assume that $V$ is closed instead of $W$?

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @jack Yes, you certainly need $V$ closed. Closedness of $W$ is unnecessary, since Hahn-Banach strictly separates points (or compact convex susbets) from closed convex subsets regardless of the ambient space being a Banach space. See "Important consequences" and "Hahn-Banach separation theorem" on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand you argument. Suppose that "any continuous linear functional on $W$ which vanishes on $V$ is identically equal to $0$." So the goal is to show $W=V$. For the sake of argument, you assumed that $W\setminus V$ is not empty, which gives the existence of an $x$. Then the Hahn-Banach Theorem gives a $\phi\in W'$ such that $V\subset\text{ker}\phi$. By our assumption, $\phi$ must be identically $0$. But $\phi$ cannot be so. Is that correct?

Comment: If $W\supsetneq V$, there exists a continuous functional $0\ne\phi\in W'$ such that $\left.\phi\right\rvert_V=0$. The contrapositive of this lemma, provided $W\supseteq V$, is that if there doesn't exist a continuous functional $\phi\in W'$ such that $\phi\ne 0$ and $\left.\phi\right\rvert_V=0$, then $W=V$. Or, that if the only continuous functional $\phi\in W'$ such that $\phi\rvert_V=0$ is $0$, then $W=V$. In this sense, "*it suffices to show*" what the text says.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. If one does have $V$ and $W$ both being closed, can one avoid using Hahn-Banach here? Can (*) imply $V$ is dense in $W$?

Comment: If you pick $w\notin V$ and specialise the result to $W=V\oplus\langle w\rangle$ (which is closed when $V$ is closed), you obtain the fact that a point and a closed vector subspace can be strictly separated by a continuous functional. Which is one of the classic consequences of Hahn-Banach. So, I guess you kinda need it for the general result.